# two different selects in grafana from influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I would like to calculate my savings of my solar power roof system.

So i have a select of my values:

```
SELECT (sum("Verbrauch")/60 - sum("Bezug")/60)  * $Strompreis_Maingau /1000 FROM "Meter" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1d) fill(null)
```

i multiply the values with the varible "Strompreis_Maingau" where the costs/kwh is configured.

So i changed my power company and i have now an other price for one kwh.

I would like to display the daily values up to 15.12.2021 with the "old" variable and from 16.12.2021 on with a new one.

When i change the select to:

```
SELECT (sum("Verbrauch")/60 - sum("Bezug")/60)  * $Strompreis_Maingau /1000 FROM "Meter" WHERE time < '2021-12-16' GROUP BY time(1d) fill(null)
```

Then i see the values only up to this date..but i would like to combine it with an addidtional select with the new variable and up from 16.12.2021.

Is this possible in some way?

Thank you!

Comment: does nobody have an idea how this could work?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the only way to calculate with the right costs is to put the costs/kwh into the database. Everytime they change you put another datapoint to the right time and the other values and the sum are correctly calculated. You can if you want display a graph with the currency of your electricity price.